# How to retrieve my Desktop folder and its contents

Tags: 14.04

While moving a text file from desktop to `/var/www/html` directory using the command:

```
$ mv /home/xyz/Desktop /var/www/html
```

I missed writing the file name after Desktop(I.e. The command should have been `$ mv home/xyz/Desktop/test.html /var/www/html`), now that I had moved an entire directory to `/var/www/html` I deleted it using the command:

```
$ rm -r Desktop
```

(while I was in the html directory). Now, although I can see the files and folders on my desktop I'm unable to access or open them, it says

```
"This location cannot be displayed, perhaps it has been deleted".
```

Please tell me how I can retrieve my files on the Desktop :(

Answer (score 2):

The files were unlinked by the `rm` command. The data is still sitting there on your disk, but the link to them has been removed.

Therefore **stop using the machine immediately** as the more you use it, the more the unlinked files get destroyed...

Please use `photorec`: you can find more information about it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Photorec) and [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step), and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJdx2ORi3r4) video shows you how to use it.

For more info : [Where do files go when the rm command is issued ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/where-do-files-go-when-the-rm-command-is-issued)

Comment: An upvote and an edit!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, the only way to retrieve them now is from backup.

After you `mv` (move) files, you still have only one copy of the file.

After you moved your Desktop to the wrong location, you should have just moved it back:

```
mv /var/www/html/Desktop /home/xyz
```

But you can't do that now because instead you removed (`rm`) them.  Once a file is removed 99.9% of the time, there's no way to get it back.

Lessons learned.